# Error Ruby on Rails: Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook is missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to add an external login with facebook, but whenever I realize the home page correctly directs me to the facebook page, but then I get the following error, and could not understand what it can be.

"Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."

```ruby
          "That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."

        raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
          else
        logger.info "No template found for #{self.class.name}\##{action_name}, rendering head :no_content" if logger
        super
```

this is my controller

```ruby
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
  def facebook
    @User = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @User.persisted?
      @User.remember_me = true
      sign_in_and_redirect @User, event: :authentication
    end
  end

end
```

this is the user model.

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth[:provider], uid: auth[:uid]).first_or_create do |user|
       if auth[:info]
         user.email = auth[:info][:email]
         user.name = auth[:info][:name]
       end

       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     end
  end
  has_many :articles , :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and i put this line in config/initializers/divise.rb

```ruby
config.omniauth :facebook, '504432376574467', 'b2bb80641fcc2ca4d28e48c5ce*******'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `User.from_omniauth` fails to create the user (possibly due to `user.password` and `user.password_confirmation` not matching), which causes the `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook` to reach the end of the method without going inside the `if` clause.

To check, you could for example add an `else` clause to your Facebook callback and `raise` an error in there.